# I can't retrieve featured image url through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to call an image to my main page (Home page). This image lives on a post and it is set as a featured image on that said post. So I got the post ID and I was able to display the title and content on the front page. But the featured image won't display the url.
 So here is the code I have on my front page:

```
<?php
$post_id = 53;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $queried_post->post_title; 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
echo $title;
echo $image;
echo $queried_post->post_content;
?>
```

It just outputs array. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem.

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
$thumb_images = wp_get_attachment_url($post_thumbnail_id);
echo $thumb_images;

//Here you will get url of featured image.
```

Answer (score 0):

This following code can help you with your problem.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); // get array of featured image

echo $image[0]; //get url of featured image of post
```